# kubectl retrieve update time for the resource

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

I'm wondering whether it's possible to get the time where my resource was updated?

e.g. via

```
$ kubectl describe deployment/myapp
```

I can see `CreationTimestamp` but I want to know the last time new changes were introduced.
Also is it possible to get a diff between two rollouts?
For example with

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment/myapp
```

I want to check the configuration difference between current version and the previous one. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: I think this thread has what you need. Link here => [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075184/how-to-check-k8s-deploy-historyl)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like these commands are sufficient

```
$ kubectl rollout history deployment myapp
$ kubectl rollout history deployment myapp --revision=76
```

and to check the difference (use `diff` or [colordiff](https://www.colordiff.org/))

```
colordiff \
    <(kubectl rollout history deployment myapp --revision=76) \
    <(kubectl rollout history deployment myapp --revision=81)
```